# Creating a CollisionObject from a mesh in indigo

Tags: ros-indigo, ur5

[image: Rosanswers logo]

im building a c++ code to move ur5_moveit_config on rviz, andvtrying to add a mesh into rviz with a ur5_moveit_config on it.
i read some previous answers and use them to build my code.
i believe my problem is at my code:

```
moveit_msgs::CollisionObject toilet;
shapes::Mesh* m = shapes::createMeshFromResource("package://home/toilet seat grubcad/toiletseat2.stl");
shape_msgs::Mesh toilet_mesh;
shapes::ShapeMsg toilet_mesh_msg;
shapes::constructMsgFromShape(m,toilet_mesh_msg);
toilet_mesh = boost::get<shape_msgs::Mesh>(toilet_mesh_msg);
toilet.meshes.resize(1);
toilet.meshes[0] = toilet_mesh;
toilet.mesh_poses.resize(1);
toilet.mesh_poses[0].position.x = 1.0;
toilet.mesh_poses[0].position.y = 1.0;
toilet.mesh_poses[0].position.z = 0.0;
toilet.mesh_poses[0].orientation.w= 1.0;
toilet.mesh_poses[0].orientation.x= 0.0;
toilet.mesh_poses[0].orientation.y= 0.0;
toilet.mesh_poses[0].orientation.z= 0.0;
//pub_co.publish(toilet);

toilet.meshes.push_back(toilet_mesh);
toilet.mesh_poses.push_back(toilet.mesh_poses[0]);
toilet.operation = toilet.ADD;

std::vector<moveit_msgs::CollisionObject> collision_objects;  
collision_objects.push_back(toilet);  

// Now, let's add the collision object into the world
ROS_INFO("Add an object into the world");  
planning_scene_interface.addCollisionObjects(collision_objects);
```

when i'm trying to "catkin_make" the program i get:

```
Built target move_arm_server
[ 50%] Built target manipulator_gazebo_generate_messages_lisp
[100%] [100%] Built target manipulator_gazebo_generate_messages_py
Built target manipulator_gazebo_generate_messages_cpp
[100%] Built target manipulator_gazebo_generate_messages
/home/noamsalo/catkin_ws/src/project/src/move_ur5_by_me.cpp:19:19: error: ‘createMeshFromResource’ is not a member of ‘shapes’
 shapes::Mesh* m = shapes::createMeshFromResource("package://home/toilet seat grubcad/toiletseat2.stl");
                   ^
/home/noamsalo/catkin_ws/src/project/src/move_ur5_by_me.cpp:21:1: error: ‘ShapeMsg’ in namespace ‘shapes’ does not name a type
 shapes::ShapeMsg toilet_mesh_msg;
 ^
/home/noamsalo/catkin_ws/src/project/src/move_ur5_by_me.cpp:22:30: error: expected constructor, destructor, or type conversion before ‘(’ token
 shapes::constructMsgFromShape(m,toilet_mesh_msg);
                              ^
/home/noamsalo/catkin_ws/src/project/src/move_ur5_by_me.cpp:23:1: error: ‘toilet_mesh’ does not name a type
 toilet_mesh = boost::get<shape_msgs::Mesh>(toilet_mesh_msg);
 ^
/home/noamsalo/catkin_ws/src/project/src/move_ur5_by_me.cpp:24:1: error: ‘toilet’ does not name a type
 toilet.meshes.resize(1);
 ^
/home/noamsalo/catkin_ws/src/project/src/move_ur5_by_me.cpp:25:1: error: ‘toilet’ does not name a type
 toilet.meshes[0] = toilet_mesh;
 ^
/home/noamsalo/catkin_ws/src/project/src/move_ur5_by_me.cpp:26:1: error: ‘toilet’ does not name a type
 toilet.mesh_poses.resize(1);
 ^
/home/noamsalo/catkin_ws/src/project/src/move_ur5_by_me.cpp:27:1: error: ‘toilet’ does not name a type
 toilet.mesh_poses[0].position.x = 1.0;
 ^
/home/noamsalo/catkin_ws/src/project/src/move_ur5_by_me.cpp:28:1: error: ‘toilet’ does not name a type
 toilet.mesh_poses[0].position.y = 1.0;
 ^
/home/noamsalo/catkin_ws/src/project/src/move_ur5_by_me.cpp:29:1: error: ‘toilet’ does not name a type
 toilet.mesh_poses[0].position.z = 0.0;
 ^
/home/noamsalo/catkin_ws/src/project/src/move_ur5_by_me.cpp:30:1: error: ‘toilet’ does not name a type
 toilet.mesh_poses[0].orientation.w= 1.0;
 ^
/home/noamsalo/catkin_ws/src/project/src/move_ur5_by_me.cpp:31:1: error: ‘toilet’ does not name a type
 toilet.mesh_poses[0].orientation.x= 0.0;
 ^
/home/noamsalo/catkin_ws/src/project/src/move_ur5_by_me.cpp:32:1: error: ‘toilet’ does not name a type
 toilet.mesh_poses[0].orientation.y= 0.0;
 ^
/home/noamsalo/catkin_ws/src/project/src/move_ur5_by_me.cpp:33:1: error: ‘toilet’ does not name a type
 toilet.mesh_poses[0].orientation.z= 0.0;
 ^
/home/noamsalo/catkin_ws/src/project/src/move_ur5_by_me.cpp:36:1: error: ‘toilet’ does not name a type
 toilet.meshes.push_back(toilet_mesh);
 ^
/home/noamsalo/catkin_ws/src/project/src/move_ur5_by_me.cpp:37:1: error: ‘toilet’ does not name a type
 toilet.mesh_poses.push_back(toilet.mesh_poses[0]);
 ^
/home/noamsalo/catkin_ws/src/project/src/move_ur5_by_me.cpp:38:1: error: ‘toilet’ does not name a type
 toilet.operation = toilet.ADD;
 ^
/home/noamsalo/catkin_ws/src/project/src/move_ur5_by_me.cpp:41:1: error: ‘collision_objects’ does not name a type
 collision_objects.push_back(toilet);  
 ^
In file included from /opt/ros/indigo/include/tf/transform_datatypes.h:44:0,
                 from /opt/ros/indigo/include/tf/time_cache.h:38,
                 from /opt/ros/indigo/include/tf/tf.h:43,
                 from /opt/ros/indigo/include/moveit/move_group_interface/move_group.h:50,
                 from /home/noamsalo/catkin_ws/src/project/src/move_ur5_by_me.cpp:1:
/opt/ros/indigo/include/ros/console.h:369:3: error: expected unqualified-id before ‘do’
   do \
   ^
/opt/ros/indigo/include/ros/console.h:557:35: note: in expansion of macro ‘ROS_LOG_COND’
 #define ROS_LOG(level, name, ...) ROS_LOG_COND(true, level, name, __VA_ARGS__)
                                   ^
/opt/ros/indigo/include/rosconsole/macros_generated.h:110:23: note: in expansion of macro ‘ROS_LOG’
 #define ROS_INFO(...) ROS_LOG(::ros::console::levels::Info, ROSCONSOLE_DEFAULT_NAME, __VA_ARGS__)
                       ^
/home/noamsalo/catkin_ws/src/project/src/move_ur5_by_me.cpp:44:1: note: in expansion of macro ‘ROS_INFO’
 ROS_INFO("Add an object into the world");  
 ^
make[2]: *** [project/CMakeFiles/move_ur5_by_me.dir/src/move_ur5_by_me.cpp.o] Error 1
make[1]: *** [project/CMakeFiles/move_ur5_by_me.dir/all] Error 2
make: *** [all] Error 2
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/234371/creating-a-collisionobject-from-a-mesh-in-indigo/) by [noamon](https://answers.ros.org/users/26866/noamon/) on ROS Answers with karma: 11 on 2016-05-15

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [kmohan](https://answers.ros.org/users/27437/kmohan/) on 2016-07-08**:
Hi noamon, I am facing the same issue. Any luck fixing it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I had the same issue. For me adding these includes solved my issue:

```
#include "geometric_shapes/shapes.h"
#include "geometric_shapes/mesh_operations.h"
#include "geometric_shapes/shape_operations.h"
```

---

Originally posted by [sbock](https://answers.ros.org/users/22154/sbock/) with karma: 51 on 2017-02-02

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2